# Identifying BIOS changes remotely

Tags: bios

Is there some way to read the BIOS log remotely?
Do changes get logged in the BIOS when a hard disk is replaced? Can this be detected after the event?

We would not like the users using the laptop for their personal benefits by replacing the hard disk on our laptops.

It has come to our notice that users are replacing the hard disk with their personal HD at home and then replacing it back with the office HD.

Comment: Depends on the make & model of machine and what management systems you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a log does not exist.

However, if you are buying business-grade laptops then you likely have management capabilities like Intel AMT. Using those features you can make it so the laptop will not boot without an authenticated hard drive attached.

Comment: also,  the laptop  will probably also need a trusted platform module, aka a TPM.

Answer (score 7):

That above, or place a sticker between the laptop and its hard disk holder case. You cheap bastards.

Comment: We already do. Thats how we found out. I was looking for a solution where we don't have to open up the laptops everyday just to verify something like this.